# How to extract bits from return code number in Bash

Tags: python, bash, pylint

I am using pylint utility that returns this error codes:

```
Pylint should leave with following status code:

* 0 if everything went fine
* 1 if a fatal message was issued
* 2 if an error message was issued
* 4 if a warning message was issued
* 8 if a refactor message was issued
* 16 if a convention message was issued
* 32 on usage error

status 1 to 16 will be bit-ORed so you can know which different
categories has been issued by analysing pylint output status code
```

Now I need to determine if fatal or error message occured in Bash. How to do that? I guess I need bit operations for that ;-)

**Edit**: I know I need to do bitwise and with number three (3) and test against null to see if fatal message or error message were issued. My problem is simple: **bash syntax to do it**. Input is $?, ouptut is again $? (e.g. using test program). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Bash you can use double parenthesis:

```
#fatal error
errorcode=7
(( res = errorcode & 3 ))
[[ $res != 0 ]] && echo "Fatal Error"
```

Comment: Thanks. I already found it and its shorter but thanks :-) [ $(($NUMBER & 3)) -ne 0 ] && echo Fatal error or error was issued

Comment: A useful variation is `( pylint $THE_PYLINT_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS; exit $(($? & 35)) )`, which zeroes out all the less-than-an-error exit codes in a way that integrates nicely into a broader script.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thanks! This should be the actual answer

Answer (score 3):

Got it!

```
[ $(($NUMBER & 3)) -ne 0 ] && echo Fatal error or error was issued
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if `$NUMBER` is `1` or `5`? :) You should test `-eq 3` see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Bash supports bitwise [operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html)...

```
$ let "x = 5>>1"
$ echo $x
2
$ let "x = 5 & 4"
$ echo $x
4
```

Comment: How to write it on the one line to test if flags "1" and "2" are set? Something like [ $? & 2 ] && echo Error. It does not work for me :-(

Answer (score 2):

A fatal message will be issued iff the status is odd, iff it has a 1 in the least significant digit.

An error message will be issued iff the status has a 1 in the next most significant digit.

So you want to check whether the last two digits are both 1; in other words, to check whether the bitwise `and` of your status code with `0b11` is three.

Comment: @lzap: oops, sorry. In that case you should check whether the final _two_ bits are both one; in other words, take the bitwise and with 0b11 == 3.

Comment: Yeah, I know what to do. What I dont know is the bash syntax for it :-) Lemme edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

To embed something like this in a script with `errexit` set, you could use a form like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
(
    rc=0;
    pylint args args || rc=$?;
    exit $(( $rc & 35 )) # fatal=1 | error=2 | usage error=32
)
```

Inspired from [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626351/how-to-extract-bits-from-return-code-number-in-bash#comment85561212_6626619) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12196502/194586)

You could poke at it by replacing the `pylint blah blah` with `python -c "exit(4+8+16)"`

Comment: If pylint exits w/ 0 then rc is never set and the "exit" line get an unbound variable error.  Setting rc=0 first solves the problem.  (THANKS Nick!)

Answer (score 1):

The return code of the last executed command in bash is available as `$?`.

```
[/tmp] % touch bar
[/tmp] % ls /tmp/bar 
/tmp/bar
[/tmp] % echo $?
0
[/tmp] % ls /tmp/baaz
ls: /tmp/baaz: No such file or directory
[/tmp] % echo $?
1
[/tmp] %
```

If you were to call an external command from say python's `subprocess` module, you could get the return code of the external command from the Popen object once the subprocess has exited.

Answer (score 1):

Using (probably sub-optimally) the bash arithmetic stuff:

```
for status in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
do
    if [ $status = 0 ]
    then echo $status: it worked perfectly
    elsif [ $(( $status & 3 )) != 0 ]
    then echo $status: a fatal or error message was sent
    else echo $status: it sort of worked mostly
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
0: it worked perfectly
1: a fatal or error message was sent
2: a fatal or error message was sent
3: a fatal or error message was sent
4: it sort of worked mostly
5: a fatal or error message was sent
6: a fatal or error message was sent
7: a fatal or error message was sent
8: it sort of worked mostly
9: a fatal or error message was sent
10: a fatal or error message was sent
11: a fatal or error message was sent
12: it sort of worked mostly
13: a fatal or error message was sent
14: a fatal or error message was sent
15: a fatal or error message was sent
16: it sort of worked mostly
```

I strongly suspect that the scripting (testing) can be made tighter or cleaner (specifically in the `elif` clause), but this seems to work (and I need to get to work).

```
pylint ...
status=$?     # Catch exit status before it changes
if [ $status = 0 ]
then echo $status: it worked perfectly
elsif [ $(( $status & 3 )) != 0 ]
then echo $status: a fatal or error message was sent
else echo $status: it sort of worked mostly
fi
```