# What is the proper way to detect shell exit code when errexit option is set?

Tags: bash, shell

I prefer to write *solid* shell code, so the errexit & nounset is always set.

The following code will stop after `bad_command`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
bad_command # stop here
good_command
```

I want to capture it, here is my method:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
rc=1
bad_command && rc=0 # stop here
[ $rc -ne 0 ] && do_err_handling
good_command
```

Is there any better or cleaner method?

My Answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
if ! bad_command ; then
  # error handling here
fi
good_command
```

Comment: Don't set `errexit` if you want to handle errors.  Handle errors if you want to handle errors.  Setting `errexit` is abdicating from your responsibility to handle errors properly.  I've never found it necessary to use `nounset`, but I am reasonably good at spelling consistently.

Comment: Always use errexit even if you want to handle errors. Any external command can fail and unless you plan on adding error handling for each|command|in|a&&work||flow then errexit will at least help protect you and the user. Same with nounset, not using it is like not using assert in other languages (because I never make errors, ever...)

Comment: FYI, none of these catch the full range of errexit codes. If your `bad_command` internally calls another command,  e.g. `bad_com2`, then errexit would crash the entire program. However, the checks listed here would miss the exit code of `bad_com2` as long as it doesn't affect the exit code of `bad_command`. Given that you're asking this question, you're probably well aware of this limitation, but others might think that these methods are a replacement for errexit :-)

Comment: My above comment shows a bad situation too - you can't have a 'test' for "will errexit causing a failure" - your only option is to enable it and see.

Comment: @Daniel In your answer, you don't need backticks around `bad_command`. I.e., `if ! bad_command; then ... fi` is enough.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

How about this?  If you want the actual exit code ...

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       
set -e

cat /tmp/doesnotexist && rc=$? || rc=$?                                         
echo exitcode: $rc        

cat /dev/null && rc=$? || rc=$?                                                 
echo exitcode: $rc
```

Output:

```
cat: /tmp/doesnotexist: No such file or directory
exitcode: 1
exitcode: 0
```

Comment: I like this method, it is lean.

Comment: why does this work? Does shell interpret this as `( command && rc=$? ) || rc=$?` ?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators

Comment: @MichelMüller it works because the whole statement works together and the final err code is 0, so errexit doesn't exit.  Yes, your interpretation, with parentheses, appears correct. In fact, you can test this: Try this ```ls fakefile && x=1 || x=2 ; echo $x```

Comment: I find having `&&` and `||` in the same line somehow unintuitive. Another way is to first define `rc=0` and only set `rc` to the actual exit code if the command failed: `rc=0; cat /tmp/doesnotexist || rc=$?`. This works because the piece of code after your `&&` will always set `rc` to zero so you could as well modify your own code to say `... && rc=0 || ...`

Comment: ok, short, but it's a bit hacky… I don't believe there is no cleaner way :-/

Comment: This is not working for me when the problem is a seg fault in the code.  To test it I have a little C program that segfaults.  Then this && || code does not get a chance to work.

Comment: @For Dummies Works with segfault for me, with https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986463/2077386 .... I get $rc=139.  Might be worth another SO question if your specific case isn't working?

Answer (score 27):

Keep with errexit.  It can help find bugs that otherwise might have unpredictable (and hard to detect) results.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit ; set -o nounset

bad_command || do_err_handle
good_command
```

The above will work fine. `errexit` only requires that the line pass, as you do with the `bad_command && rc=0`.  Therefore, the above with the 'or' will only run do_err_handle if `bad_command` fails and, as long as do_err_handle doesn't also 'fail', then the script will continue.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. To expand further,

bad_command || { echo "My error message explaining why the crash"; exit 1}

Comment: Note that the two `set` can be combined into one `set -o errexit -o nounset`.

Comment: It is dangerous to use ||, && and ! if your bad_command is a function. See my answer for workaround.

Comment: `cmd || { echo "error msg"; exit 1; }` is a *terrible* idea.  You do not know why `cmd` failed, and you cannot explain it.  If `cmd` fails, it should write its own error message, because it has the context to write a useful error message.  Also, error messages belong on stderr, so at best you can write `echo 'cmd failed for some reason' >&2`.  But it is best to just write `cmd || exit`.  If `cmd` is so poorly written that it doesn't write a decent error message, then you should not be using it at all.

Answer (score 9):

A slight variation of the answer given by @rrauenza. Since the `&& rc=$?` part is their answer will always be equal to `&& rc=0` one can as well set `rc` to `0` before running the command. The result ends up more readable in my opinion because the variable is defined upfront in its own line of code and is only changed if the command exits with a non-zero exit status. If `nounset` is also given, then it's now clear that `rc` was indeed never undefined. This also avoids mixing `&&` and `||` in the same line which might be confusing because one might not always know the operator precedence by heart.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       
set -eu

rc=0
cat /tmp/doesnotexist || rc=$?                                         
echo exitcode: $rc        

rc=0
cat /dev/null || rc=$?                                                 
echo exitcode: $rc
```

Output:

```
cat: /tmp/doesnotexist: No such file or directory
exitcode: 1
exitcode: 0
```

Comment: I like that, too!  I might put `rc=0; cat /tmp/foo || rc=$?` on one line ... maybe.

Answer (score 7):

Continue to write solid shell code.

You do it right if bad_command is really a command.
But be careful with function calls in if, while, ||, && or !, because errexit will not work there. It may be dangerous.

If your bad_command is actually bad_function you should write this:

```
set -eu 

get_exit_code() {
    set +e
    ( set -e;
      "$@"
    )
    exit_code=$?
    set -e
}

...

get_exit_code bad_function

if [ "$exit_code" != 0 ]; then
    do_err_handle
fi
```

This works well in bash 4.0. In bash 4.2 you only get exit codes 0 or 1.

Update: No problem with exit codes in bash 5.0.

Comment: Can you expand on what to do so it works well in bash 4.2? Also, what about newer bash versions (4.3, 4.4, 5.0)?

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I've referenced it in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76861665/130638

Answer (score 6):

```
set -o errexit

bad_command || {
  resp_code=$?
  echo Bad Thing $resp_code happened
}
```

Comment: I wish I could vote 18 more times to make this the top answer

Answer (score 4):

A common way to avoid exiting a Bash program when `errexit` is set and a command that may fail is run is to precede the command with `!`.

After the command has run `$?` does not contain the exit status of the command.  (It contains 0 if the command failed and 1 otherwise.)  However, the PIPESTATUS array does contain the exit status of the command.  A safe way to capture the exit status of a command that may fail, whether or not `errexit` is set, is:

```
! bad_command
rc=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

The second line can be simplified to `rc=$PIPESTATUS`, but Shellcheck will complain about it.

If (as is often the case) you don't need to know the exit status of the command, just if it succeeded or failed, then the solution by @george is good if the error handler is a one-liner.  For multi-line error handlers a good option is:

```
if ! bad_command ; then
    # Handle errors here
fi
```

Note that (except in very unusual circumstances) it would **not** be correct to use `` `bad_command` `` (as suggested in the question) instead of plain `bad_command`.  You can use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to get the exit status of the command if it is needed in the error handling code, since `$?` doesn't contain it in this case either.

Comment: Note, `PIPESTATUS` is an array because it works also on multiple commands, for example given `! good_cmd_one | bad_cmd_two`, we would get `${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0` and ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 1`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with functions, also it disables errexit for the bad_command.

Comment: @balupton, I haven't seen any problems using this with functions.  For instance, `bash -ce 'function bad_command { return 1; }; ! bad_command; rc=${PIPESTATUS[0]}; echo "rc=$rc"'` outputs `rc=1`, indicating that the function return value has been successfully detected.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to detect the exit code of a compound list (or a function), and have `errexit` and `nounset` applied there, you can use this kind of code:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
unset -v unbound_variable

f() {
    echo "before false"
    false
    echo "after false"
}

g() {
    echo "before unbound"
    var=$unbound_variable
    echo "after unbound"
}

set +e
(set -e; f)
echo error code of f = $?
set -e

echo still in main program

set +e
(set -e; g)
echo error code of g = $?
set -e

echo still in main program
```

The above should print non-zero error codes for both functions `f` and `g`, though you might want that the script exits immediately after unbound variable error. I suppose this works by any POSIX shell. You can also detect the error code in EXIT trap, but the shell exits thereafter. The problem with other proposed methods is that the `errexit` setting is ignored when an exit status of such a compound list is tested. Here is a quote from the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set):

> The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list
> following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, a pipeline
> beginning with the ! reserved word, or any command of an AND-OR list
> other than the last.

Note that if you have defined your function like

```
f() (
    set -e
    ...
)
```

it is enough to do

```
set +e
f
echo exit code of f = $?
set -e
```

to get the exit code.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with comments, so if you can give up `errexit` then you can easily shorten your code to

```
 bad_command || do_err_handle
 good_command
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I don't want to give up errexit. You give me good hint.

Comment: To expand on this:

bad_command || { echo "My error message explaining why the crash"; exit 1}

Comment: No.  *Never* write `bad_command || { echo "My error message"; exit 1; }`  Ever.  If you are going to do that, you *must* write `echo "My error message" >&2` because error messages belong on stderr.  But that should really be `echo "My useless error message that is just noise" >&2` because you don't have enough insight into what `bad_command` did to write a good error message.  Just write `bad_command || exit` and rely on `bad_command` to write a good error message.  If it doesn't write good messages, then it is truly a bad command and you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

what if you want to know exit status of bad_command?

I think the simplest way is to disable errexit:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit

some_code_here

set +o errexit
bad_command
status=$?
set -o errexit
process $status
```

Comment: This technique is ok if you only have to catch one command, but if you want to correctly handle lots of commands that may return codes (like grep, diff etc) then it'll prove painful.

Comment: @PaulHargreaves but this seems really the only way to get the error code of the command. Probably needed, but useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

In *bash* you can use the trap builtin which is quite nice.  See
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79648/how-to-trigger-error-using-trap-command

Not sure how portable it is with other shells.. so YMMV

Edit.. comment below informs me that this is not portable so take care.

Comment: ERR trap is not portable, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31313305/4414935

Answer (score 1):

A clean reliable way to error exit

```
command_that_error_exits || { echo "Line $LINENO: Failed with Error" 1>&2; exit 1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to complete the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201766/2609399
, which is a very good catch, BTW.

I've faced this limitation a time ago and applied a similar fix for it. Please consider the below code sample.

```
invokeBashFunction() {
  local functionExitCode="0"
  /bin/bash -c "
    set -o errexit

    ${*}
  " || functionExitCode="${?}"

  # add some additional processing logic/code

  return "${functionExitCode}"
}
export -f invokeBashFunction
```

And there are few example of how to use it:

```
invokeBashFunction bad_function param1 "param 2" param3 && echo "It passed." || echo "It failed!"
```

```
if invokeBashFunction bad_function param1 "param 2" param3
then
  echo "It passed."
fi
```

```
if ! invokeBashFunction bad_function param1 "param 2" param3
then
  echo "It failed!"
fi
```

Comment: How to I make the `bad_function` available within the `/bin/bash -c` call?

Comment: `export -f bad_function` into the source file...

Answer (score 0):

I cobbled together a (hopefully) textbook example from all the answers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# exit immediately on error
set -o errexit

file='dfkjlfdlkj'
# Turn off 'exit immediately on error' during the command substitution
blah=$(set +o errexit && ls $file) && rc=$? || rc=$?
echo $blah
# Do something special if $rc
(( $rc )) && echo failure && exit 1
echo success
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the early answers and they did not work when calling a program that segfaults.  My use case is trying to catch a rare segfault and reporting which of a few thousand inputs caused it to occur.  Instead, I based it on

```
   if [ $(./segfault >realstdout || echo error) == "error" ]
   then
      echo this died # and report details
   else
      echo strange success
   fi
```

This seems convoluted but I have not found a cleaner way.

Comment: You could replace the first line by `if ! ./segfault >realstdout`. Do you even need  `realstdout`?

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is good, but I think it could be refactored to be even better; more generic, easier to refactor and read:

```
some_command_status=$(some_command && echo $? || echo $?)
```

vs.

```
some_command && some_command_status=$? || some_command_status=$?
```

Comment: Note that using `$(some_command ...)` may create an extra subprocess (particularly in Bash) and cause performance problems.  Also, there are rare circumstances where a command will behave significantly differently if run in a subprocess.