# Portably trapping ERR in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, dash-shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that aborts when a command fails and displays the offending line number.

```
set -e
trap 'echo "$0 FAILED at line ${LINENO}"' ERR
```

Turned out the trap line does not work with Ubuntu's default shell script interpreter, dash. If I change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` this works but not with `#!/bin/sh`. Is there a way to make this work without relying on bash being present?

By the way, The error I get from dash is this:

```
trap: ERR: bad trap
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can trap on exit and test the exit code like this:

```
set -e
trap '[ $? -eq 0 ] && exit 0 || echo "$0 FAILED at line ${LINENO}"' EXIT
```

Comment: The line number doesn't seem to work without bash though. Not for me at least.

Comment: Seems that `$LINENO` is not available in dash.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.24LINENO

Comment: So it is supported in dash but debian builds the package with `--disable-lineno` flag.  They do this because autoconf would select dash as the shell to use and that causes many other packages to fail to install properly.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582952

Comment: Interesting. So from what I gather, `LINENO` is indeed part of POSIX so you could say using it is portable (hence the question requirement is met), on the other hand looks like what lots of people have on their machines has it disabled. I don't know what the situation is on other shells and I'm still unsure whether I should switch the accepted answer...

Comment: Having thought a bit more about this, since the currently accepted answer does not provide an alternative, I'll switch to yours.

Comment: dash-0.5.11.5-2.fc37.x86_64 on Fedora has LINENO enabled, but I'm seeing dash print the line number within the trap string (1 unless you write it multiline), not of the line that caused EXIT . Makes this pretty useless compared to `set -e`.  EXIT also has "false positives" when script is _deliberately_ exiting non-0 in a way that's not a bug...

Answer (score 7):

> According to various sources on the internets, ERR is not standard at
>   all and only supported by the Korn Shell - which seemed to invent it -
>   and Bash, which seemed to adopt it.
>   https://github.com/bmizerany/roundup/issues/25#issuecomment-10978764

I would go for the easy solution.

Simply change

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or better

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: That's how I did it in the end. Not exactly an answer to my question but since you provide a source for it not being possible, I'm accepting it. Thank you.